# Does creating an object of a class in every iteration corrupts memory

Tags: c++11, memory-leaks

I have two classes let's call them A and B

```
class A
{
   ....some function definitions..
   specialFunc1(int count, B b)
   {
        stores data in the class B's object to its own containers
        and count is an integer which maps data from b to an int using
        std::map
   }
};


class B
{
      Has containers which are processing and storing data
      and class A can access these containers because they have public
      access specifier

 };



 int main()
 {

    A a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
         B b;
         Then b call its methods to store data in desired containers
         a.specialFun1(i,a);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

My code is as described above, it has two classes let's call them A and B which are interacting with each other.

Class B loads in some data inside the loop in the main function does some processing on it and then passes it to class A which maps each iteration's data to a std::map.

And every successive iteration defines object b again and again.

My understanding is, since object b scope is just within the loop as soon as the iteration completes it should go out of memory and hence a new definition of b should not mess up with the memory on the stack.

Am I right in thinking this or it can potentially cause memory corruption due to successive allocation and deallocation inside the class object b.

Comment: It's hard to answer any questions about memory corruption without looking at real code. Pseudo code doesn't give enough information.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right in thinking this or it can potentially cause memory corruption due to successive allocation and deallocation inside the class object b.

You are right. Successive allocation and deallocation is allowed in C++, and as such doesn't in general cause memory corruption.

Of course, any code that has undefined behaviour could corrupt memory. The shown *(incomplete)* code doesn't demonstrate undefined behaviour.